# Django positive validation not checking python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

But with my below code it is not checking the validation rule and allowing the positive start and positive end values in the conjunction.

my code in django form.py

```html
d=[]
b=[]
my_tuple = []
for i in range(count):
      start_new = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-start_new') or 0)
      start_old = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-start_old') or 0)
      end_new = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-end_new') or 0)
      end_old = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-end_old') or 0)
      d.append((start_new,start_old))
      b.append((end_new,end_old))
      my_tuple.append((d[0],b[0]))
      for i in my_tuple[0]:
           my_result = [sub for sub in i if all(element >= 0 for element in sub)]
           if len(my_result)>2:
               raise ValidationError(
                    f" Positive Start  values and Positive End  values are not allowed to be used in conjunction")
```